# Variable is not returning the correct value from a function

Tags: python, function

I have this code and the output isn't 1 as I expected but 0.

```
x = 1
def winconditions():
    if x == 1:
        pwin = 1
        return pwin

pwin = 0
while pwin == 0:
    winconditions()
    print (pwin)
```

Comment: you have to set pwin global

Comment: Also, note that `return pwin` is useless in your current code, as you don't do anything with the return value when calling `winconditions()`. You should use it by assigning it to `pwin`: `pwin = winconditions()`.

Comment: better run as `pwin = winconditions(pwin, x)` and don't use external/global values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare variable `pwin` as global:

```
def winconditions():
    global pwin
    if x == 1:
        pwin = 1
```

otherwise will be a local variable, which won't have any effect on the `pwin` variable you declared outside the function.

Please note that using global variables is usually a bad programming style. This might be an interesting read:
[Are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)

Answer (score 0):

when you set `pwin = 1` inside `winconditions` you are creating a **local** varible called `pwin` and returning it, you are not modifying the global `pwin`.

```py
x = 1
def winconditions():
    global pwin # This is needed to modify the external variable
    if x == 1:
        pwin = 1
        return pwin

pwin = 0
while pwin == 0:
    winconditions()
    print (pwin)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop set the value of pwin to the winconditions().

pwin = wincondition()

You have a scope issue here, as you have declared the function wincondition before you declare the variable pwin

Answer (score 0):

**You can** just add a `global` declaration to the `pwin` variable

```
x = 1
def winconditions():
    if x == 1:
        global pwin  # <--- Edited line
        pwin = 1
        return pwin

pwin = 0
while pwin == 0:
    winconditions()
    print (pwin)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, variables declared in a function is locally scoped. If you want to declare it globally, you can use the global keyword, like this:

```py
def win_conditions():
    global pwin
    if x == 1:
        pwin = 1
        return pwin
```

However, setting global variables in function is generally a bad practice. Instead, you can probably make use of the walrus operator in the while loop, which was added in 3.8.

```py
x = 1
def win_conditions():
    if x == 1:
        pwin = 1
        return pwin

while (pwin := win_conditions()) == 0:
    print (pwin)
```

Or, just simply set the variable `pwin` to the output of the function:

```py
x = 1
def win_conditions():
    if x == 1:
        pwin = 1
        return pwin

pwin = 0
while pwin == 0:
    pwin = win_conditions()
    print (pwin)
```